# Write array of radix-2 numeric strings to binary file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, io, bindata

I've written a simple Huffman encoding in Ruby. As output I've got an array, for example:

```
["010", "1111", "10", "10", "110", "1110", "001", "110", "000", "10", "011"]
```

I need to write, and then read, it to and from a file. I tried several methods:

```
IO.binwrite("out.cake", array)
```

I get a simple text file and not binary.

Or:

```
File.open("out.cake", 'wb' ) do |output|
  array.each do | byte |
       output.print byte.chr
  end
end
```

Which looks like it works, but then I can't read it into array.

Which encoding should I use?

Comment: What do you want your file to contain? Characters? Or bits? Or Ruby array? Or something else?

Comment: Bits. Coz I need less file size.

Comment: The answer is likely to involve using `pack`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think you can just use `Array#pack` and `String#unpack` like the following code:

```
# Writing
a = ["010", "1111", "10", "10", "110", "1110", "001", "110", "000", "10", "011"]
File.open("out.cake", 'wb' ) do |output|
  output.write [a.join].pack("B*")
end

# Reading
s = File.binread("out.cake")
bits = s.unpack("B*")[0] # "01011111010110111000111000010011"
```

I don't know your preferred format for the result of reading and I know the above method is inefficient. But anyway you can take "0" or "1" sequentially from the result of `unpack` to traverse your Huffman tree.

Comment: @IvanKozlov Here you can see how to read the bits back to string. Now you just need to split it into pieces using Huffman decoding.

Answer (score 4):

If you want bits, then you have to do both packing and unpacking manually. Neither Ruby nor any other common-use language will do it for you.

Your array contains strings that are groups of characters, but you need to build an array of bytes and write those bytes into the file.

From this: `["010", "1111", "10", "10", "110", "1110", "001", "110", "000", "10", "011"]`

you should build these bytes: `01011111 01011011 10001110 00010011`

Since it's just four bytes, you can put them into a single 32-bit number `01011111010110111000111000010011` that is `5F5B8E13` hex.

Both samples of your code do different things. The first one writes into the file a string representation of a Ruby array. The second one writes 32 bytes where each is either `48` ('0') or `49` ('1').

If you want bits, then your output file size should be just four bytes.

Read about bit operations to learn how to achieve that.

---

Here is a draft.
I didn't test it. Something may be wrong.

```
a = ["010", "1111", "10", "10", "110", "1110", "001", "110", "000", "10", "011"]

# Join all the characters together. Add 7 zeros to the end.
bit_sequence = a.join + "0" * 7  # "010111110101101110001110000100110000000"

# Split into 8-digit chunks.
chunks = bit_sequence.scan(/.{8}/)  # ["01011111", "01011011", "10001110", "00010011"]

# Convert every chunk into character with the corresponding code.
bytes = chunks.map { |chunk| chunk.to_i(2).chr }  # ["_", "[", "\x8E", "\x13"]

File.open("my_huffman.bin", 'wb' ) do |output|
  bytes.each { |b| output.write b }
end
```

Note: seven zeros are added to handle case when the total number of characters is not divisible by 8. Without those zeros, `bit_sequence.scan(/.{8}/)` will drop the remaining characters.

Comment: Could you paste some sample code? For may array, how to pack and unpack it?

Comment: Basically Huffman codes is used for compression or archiving. So as a result I'd like to have file with minimum size. Your ideas about it? Which method do you suggest?

Comment: I added a draft just as an example. I did not have a time to test it carefully.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is really useful. And one last question: how can I read "my_huffman.bin" to initial array?

Comment: Look at M. Shiina's answer. It's even better than mine. I was not quite familiar with pack("B*").