# Streaming file from mounted smb filesystem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, streaming, mount, samba, smb

Im mounting an samba share from our Windows fileserver to our webserver so that the employees can  transfer data to our fileexchange portal via their samba shares.

I want to stream these files via the `send_file` method which doesnt work well with big files. It seems that the `send_file` method waits till it has loaded the complete file which can take a very long time over the 100mbit network.

By default the `:stream` option is set to `true` and I also set it to true manually but it doesnt help. The method always waits till the whole file is loaded. I think the problem is that Im trying to stream from the samba share. Is there any mounting option that could help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to obscure nature of MS technologies and protocols and unknowns regarding your system setup, rails version etc, I kinda have a feeling you might not get the answer you are looking for.

So, if this unwanted case happens, let me give a couple of alternatives...

**Alternative 1**

Set up a web server on the SMB host to serve the files, mount the folder in apache and stream them over HTTP directly to the client without the webapp as the middleman

**Alternative argh :-(**

If all else fails,

considering you have a relatively small number of users and high network latency it might prove a decent enough choice to simply stream file contents using regular `File.open` ([How do I read/write binary files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821435/how-do-i-read-write-binary-files)) and Rails' inbuilt streaming (this will depend on your rails version, Rails 4 should handle this well, Rails 3 is doable too)