# Why Ruby does not read all bytes from a file

Tags: ruby, file

I am learning ruby, and I want to read a file bytewise.
It work fine with short text files, but It stop reading bytes when I try it with an image or pdf file.

I tried different implementations but I got the same result. Here is my code:

```
destination = File("file2", "w")
source = File.open("file1", "r")
source.each_byte do |byte|
    destination.print (byte).chr
end
destination.close
```

I tried this too:

```
destination = File("file2", "w")
source = File.open("file1", "r")
source.each_byte do |byte|
    destination.putc(byte)
end
destination.close
```

I compare the original `source` image file:
[image: Original Image]

And the new image `destination`:
[image: New image]

I saw that `0x0D` and `0x0A` correspond with `\r` and `\n`.

When I test the code manually in `irb` I see that read fine the 4 initial elements, and then ignore the 5th (`0x0D` = `\r`) element, and get the next one (`0x0A` = `\n`).

When I run the code with a pdf file, I see that in the original file:
[image: Original pdf]

And this in the new pdf file:
[image: New pdf]

When I do `source.read(1)` I get the correct values `\r` and `\n`.

Why `.getbyte` ignore the `0x0D` byte (`\r`), and say that there aren't more bytes?

Can I get the decimal value from the `"\r"` and `"\n"` strings?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929610/automatically-open-a-file-as-binary-with-ruby

Comment: Well-written question, but possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/16821435/1301972

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already solved.

I was trying with different encodings, and I tried opening the `source` file in binary mode, but It got another error because I forgot open the `destination` file in binary mode too.

**It read all bytes fine, and write fine too, opening both files in binary mode.**

Here, my code:

```
destination = File("file2", "wb")
source = File.open("file1", "rb")
source.each_byte do |byte|
    destination.print (byte).chr
end
destination.close
source.close
```